# How to increase selectivity for a class with :hover?

Tags: css, angular

I have a `<mat-tree>` component where styling for dependant `<mat-tree-node>`'s introduces a special background color for mouse hovering:

```
mat-tree-node {
  // ...
  &:hover {
    background: $hoverColor;
  }
}
```

In the tree, some elements may be selected by the user. In order to highlight them visually, a special class is applied to `<mat-tree-node>` as `[class.highlight]="isHighlighted(node)"` and the class is defined as follows:

```
highlight {
  background-color: $selectColor;
}
```

My problem arises when a node is selected and hovered at the same time. I want the `selectedColor` to take priority but the node gets `hoverColor` background when hovered. I changed the definition to this:

```
mat-tree-node.highlight {
  background-color: $selectColor;
  &:hover {
    background-color: $selectColor;
  }
}
```

Google Chrome developer console started to show the class higher in the stack as now it has +1 point of selectivity, but when hovering, the `hoverColor` is still being applied to the background, and even `!important` does not help.

Why does not it obey the new definition and how to fix it?

Comment: http://w3.org/tr/selectors/#specificity

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik it is well-known where to find the documentation, the problem is that I probably misread it. If you know the answer, could you be more specific and explain why does my solution not work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mat-tree-node.highlight {
    background-color: $selectColor;
}

may-tree-node:not(.highlight):hover {
    background-color: $hoverColor;
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! But why does not it work when two classes have `:hover`? Do I misread the documentation on selectivity?